# Submit form using enter without triggering page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I know it is possible to submit a form using the enter key, but doing so refreshes the page.

I am making an interactive game where the user's responses are added to a `div` whenever he makes a response (submits the form).

However, by refreshing the page, the current text in the `div` disappears, and thus this is NOT desired.

Is it possible to trigger a script using the enter key when you submit a form WITHOUT the page refreshing?

Illustrated example:

```
<form action="tdat.php" method="post" onsubmit="return answer(event)">
    <input type="text" name="userInput" id="searchTxt" maxlength="50" size="50">
</form>
```

This is the form that I am using. I tried making a function `answer(e)` to respond to the user's input, and display the text to the `div`.

However, the code `answer(e)` does not run, and the page also refreshes. How should I combat this? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

To those wondering the contents of the event in `answer(e)` it is as follows:

```
function answer(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        addText()
        responseCheck()
        document.getElementById("searchTxt").value = ""
        autoScroll()
    }
}
```

`addText()` is the one that appends the `HTML` to the `div`, `responseCheck()` is the function that calculates the response and the rest should be obvious.

Comment: what is event? in answer?

Comment: Updated to be clearer. Thanks @uzaif for the reminder.

Comment: try keydown event in input and check for event.keyCode ==13 because you dont have submit button

Comment: just add onkeydown in input may be it will work

Comment: That works, but it causes the page to refresh, causing the text to appear in the div briefly before the page reloads. is there a way to prevent the reload?

Comment: remove form and create use ajax inside function

Comment: will i post as answer if you find my information useful

Comment: Ok I find it useful, trying to convert to ajax now. Perhaps you can suggest an example? Does this work?

`if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            addText()
            $.ajax({
                url: "localhost/tdat/tdat.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    'userInput': $userResponse
                }
            })`

Comment: okey can i post as answer

Comment: ya did you use event.preventDefault?

Comment: does it work  now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First Add onkeydown in input and remove the form tag which cause
>   reload whole page

```
<input type="text" name="userInput" id="searchTxt" maxlength="50" size="50" onkeydown="return answer(event)">
```

now use below js function

```
function answer(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        addText();
        $.ajax({
        url:"tdat.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:$("#searchTxt").val(),
        success:function(){
          $("searchTxt").val("");
          autoScroll()

        }
       })
     }
}
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: include jquery library

Answer (score 0):

Use preventDefault() in your js function to suppress "enter" default behaviour.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Answer (score 0):

> First of all you will need to remove the action attribute from the
>   form tag.

Then, if you're using jQuery

```
$('input[type=text]').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();

        /* AJAX code to post data to action */
        /* add Div based on response from AJAX call */
    }
});
```

The above snippet will run whenever a key is pressed while a text field is in focus. If the pressed key is the enter button then it will enter the if block where you can write your code to call your action using AJAX.